# Writing a function that always returns the value "1" in R and in C++

Tags: c++, r

I wish to make a very simple function that takes no arguments and always
returns the integer 1 in R and C++ respectively.

R:

```
 oneR <- function() 1L
```

But when I write 'oneR' the console returns `function() 1L` and not `1`.

Even when I write `oneR(3)` (or some other number) I don't get `1` but an error saying that `Error in oneR(10) : unused argument (10)`

The C++ equavalent is

```
cppFunction('
int oneCpp() { # C++ function
return 1;
}')
```

My problem is just the R function.

Comment: `return(1L)`maybe? Actually you can't use arguments when you didn't define any.

Comment: Just use `oneR <- function(x) 1`

Comment: You need to actually call your function (which is defined perfectly fine): oneR()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your way of calling the function. `oneR <- function() 1L` implies 0 arguments. As such `oneR(10)` will return an error, as an argument is given but none is specified in the function body.

Instead `oneR()` will return your value correctly.

If you wish for it to not return a warning ever simply extend the function

```
oneR <- function(...) 1L
```

No matter what you put into the function, it will now return 1 and ignore all arguments.

```
oneR(10, C = 20, 30) 
[1] 1
```

Note that `1L` will return 1 as integer while `1` would return a double precision float.

Comment: You are thinking way to complicated. OP just doesn't know how to call a function. Their function is fine.

Comment: Which is exactly what i stated. 'The problem is in your way of calling the function'

Comment: I discovered that `oneR` made no sense since the function of course needs arguments, but adding the ellipsis (...) helped alot in my understanding.

Comment: I am glad i could help. :-)